# Find currently active View Struct/Class name (on mobile/simulator) in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working on someone else code in SwiftUI and I am unable to locate the view name that is currently running on mobile device.

In storyboard applications we can get the name of currently active viewController by debugging the view hierarchy as shown in image below.

[image: Active ViewController name in storyboard]

But this method does not work for SwiftUI application. I have also attached the screenshot of SwiftUI application below. For image below it can be seen that there is no information of currently active View for the SwiftUI application.

[image]

Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @chrigu not yet

Answer (score 0):

Selecting view in view debug area we can see that specific view type in the view hierarchy navigation path (at the top):

[image: demo]

Comment: In my case its just showing the hostingView.